# Change multiple attributes with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, rel

I'm building an image gallery and have been able to get the clicked thumbnail image to be loaded in the main #large div a new src for the  tag.
I'm trying to get the rel attribute also, in order to populate the rel attribute in the  tag.

Here's my code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.thumbnail').live("click", function() {
        $('#large').hide();
        $('#project-image').css('background-image', "url('/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat");

     //   var i = $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function() {

        var i = $('<img />').attr({    
        src: this.href,
        rel: MISSING REL SELECTOR

        }).load(function() {




            $('#large').attr('src', i.attr('src'));
            $('#large').attr('rel', i.attr('rel'));
          $('#project-image').css('background-image', 'none');
            $('#large').fadeIn();
    });

        return false; 
    });
});
```

What's the proper selector to load the rel attribute in the i array?

Comment: see http://saving.edoardobiasini.it/project/view/project_4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need a

```
$(this).children('img').attr('rel')
```

in place of your MISSING REL SELECTOR

Comment: no luck… I still get the original rel attribute in the loaded image

Comment: does the $('a.thumbnail') contain the rel attribute you need?, or is it maybe an img inside the $('a.thumbnail')?
a working example might be useful :P

Comment: oh, I see that those $('a.thumbnail')  do not have rel tags, maybe you want to add the title attrs instead? ( for the ones that have it, some dont )
as in $(this).attr('title')

Comment: I would prefer to get the rel element... I can populate all of them... test with the 1st and 4th thumbnails, as they have rel attributes....

Comment: yup, those are the ones that have title and alt attributes, but no rels :P

Comment: You are right! Sorry... could you check now? They should have a rel attribute now, but it won't change the rel attribute on the #large img once clicked.

Comment: Updated the answer, you need need a children!, I tested it so it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about the children property... could you point to some documental source about this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/children/  It's like find(), but for children instead of descendants

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
rel: this.attr('rel')
```

Comment: unfortunately it seems to break the .loading function, as the image gets opened in a blank window...

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `$(this).attr('rel')`, and not simply `this.attr('rel')`.

Comment: no luck... the .loading function won't break, but I the rel attribute won't update